# Is there a necessary and sufficient condition to determine whether a number sequence can serve as the first few moments of a Radon measure?

Tags: pr.probability, matrices

Given a few positive numbers $(M_1, M_2,\cdots, M_K)$, they are the moments of a measure if
\begin{equation}
    M_k = \int d\mu(x)  x^k,\quad k = 1,2,\cdots,K.
\end{equation}
This is related to the moment problem in optimization. Consider the Hankel matrix:
\begin{equation}
    H_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    M_1 & M_2 \\
M_2 & M_3
\end{bmatrix},\quad H_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
    M_1 & M_2 & M_3\\
M_2 & M_3 & M_4\\
M_3 & M_4 & M_5
\end{bmatrix},\cdots
\end{equation}
One necessary condition is all $\det(H_{2n+1}) > 0, 2n+1 \le K$.

Is there any literature also working on the necessary and sufficient condition for this problem?

PS: more precisely, suppose $d\mu$ is in the form of
\begin{equation}
    d\mu(x) = \sum_{i}w_i \delta(x - x_i),
\end{equation}
the question is what is the equivalent condition for $(M_1, M_2,\cdots, M_K)$ to not support an answer with $\exists i, w_i < 0$?

Comment: Over what interval (?) are the integrals?

Comment: Yes, there is an infinite amount of literature. Search for "truncated moment problem", or see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610882.pdf

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

For integers $l\ge0$, consider the following $(l+1)\times(l+1)$ matrices:
$$R_{2l}:=(M_{i+j-2})_{i,j,=1}^{l+1},\quad 
R_{2l+1}:=(M_{i+j-1})_{i,j,=1}^{l+1}$$
(assuming $M_0=1$).

If your integrals are over the interval $[0,\infty)$, then a necessary and sufficient condition for your moment problem is that $R_K$ and $R_{K-1}$ be positive semidefinite.

If your integrals are over the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, then a necessary and sufficient condition for your moment problem is that $R_{2m}$ be positive semidefinite, where $m:=\lfloor K/2\rfloor$.

(See e.g. [page 781](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/37594110_Optimal_Inequalities_in_Probability_Theory_A_Convex_Optimization_Approach).)

---

After this answer was posted, the OP added the condition that the measure $\mu$ be supported on a finite set.

However, the above conditions on the moments are sufficient for the existence of $\mu$ even with this additional condition. Indeed, let $H$ denote the nonempty set of probability measures with prescribed moments $M_1,\dots,M_K$. By (say) Theorem 3.1 of [Winkler](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689944?origin=JSTOR-pdf&typeAccessWorkflow=login), the set $\text{ex }H$ of the extreme points of $H$ is nonempty. Moreover, by Theorem 2.1 of [Winkler](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689944?origin=JSTOR-pdf&typeAccessWorkflow=login), each element of the set $\text{ex }H$ is a measure supported on a finite set. Thus, there is an element of the set $\text{ex }H\subseteq H$ that is a measure supported on a finite set. $\quad\Box$

---

**Correction:** The cited results on [page 781](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/37594110_Optimal_Inequalities_in_Probability_Theory_A_Convex_Optimization_Approach) hold only if the relevant matrices $R_\cdot$ are nonsingular. In general, as [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456316/is-there-a-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-to-determine-whether-a-number-sequ/456334?noredirect=1#comment1182418_456334) by Tobias Fritz, one can use [Theorems 3.1 and 3.9 of Curto and Fialkow](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/v017n4/0603CURTO.pdf), which also immediately provide for the existence of a measure $\mu$ supported on a finite set and having the presribed moments.

Comment: I feel this is only a necessary condition, not necessary and sufficient. More precisely, suppose dμ
 is in the form of
dμ(x)=∑iwiδ(x−xi),
the question is what is the equivalent condition for (M1,M2,⋯,MK)
 to not support an answer with ∃i,wi<0
?

Comment: @YiChanghao : The condition that $\mu$ be of this form has been added after this answer was posted. Such additions, which may invalidate a valid answer, should never be made. Anyhow, I have now added an explanation why the previously given conditions on the moments are sufficient for the existence of $\mu$ even with this additional condition.

Comment: This answer isn't quite right: it would let you conclude that there is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ whose moments up to the fourth are given by the sequence $(1,0,0,0,1)$. This is obviously not the case since vanishing variance implies vanishing fourth moment. The correct answer includes an additional rank condition; see e.g. Theorems 3.1 and 3.9 in [Curto and Fialkow (pdf)](https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/v017n4/0603CURTO.pdf) or Section 9.6 in [Schmüdgen's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-64546-9).

Comment: @TobiasFritz : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: no problem, nice to see the correction!

Comment: @YiChanghao : Do you have a further response to this answer?

Comment: Let me think about it

Comment: @YiChanghao : Let me know if anything seems unclear or concerning to you.